# JavaScript animation setInterval / clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I need to make an animation of:
a box which gets wider and moves to the right until it reach a size limit and then gets thinner again.
(i tried to give higher values to the "bigger" interval, then clear it and let the "smaller" interval to continue play and shrink it, 
what it actually does: it gets to 200px and then goes bigger and smaller by 5px repetitively and keep moving right)

```
 function animatesmall(name, dist, time) {
     $(name).animate({
         left: dist
     }, time);
     $(name).css({
         width: numberup
     });
     numberup = numberup - 5;
 }

 var numberup = 1;

 function animatebig(name, dist, time) {
     if (numberup < 200) {
         $(name).animate({
             left: dist
         }, time);
         $(name).css({
             width: numberup
         });
         numberup = numberup + 10;
     } else {
         clearInterval(bigger);
     }
 }

 $(function () {
     var bigger = setInterval(function () {
         animatebig('.box1', "+=1", 100)
     }, 100);

     var smaller = setInterval(function () {
         animatesmall('.box1', "+=1", 100)
     }, 100);
 });
```

Comment: please use proper code indention.

Comment: i did:
I need to make an animation of: a box which gets wider and moves to the right until it reach a size limit and then gets thinner again. (i tried to give higher values to the "bigger" interval, then clear it and let the "smaller" interval to continue play and shrink it, what it actually does: it gets to 200px and then goes bigger and smaller by 5px repetitively and keep moving right)

Comment: 1 - `var bigger` is only defined within `$(function() {` scope, therefore calling `clearInterval(bigger)` outside that scope does nothing. 2 - The object will keep moving right because you tell it to do so in both `animatebig` and `animatesmall`

Comment: huu ok i see...i'll go fight this again with that tip, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until "numberup" reaches 200, you're effectively adding 10 and subtracting 5 from the width

when it reaches over 200, you only subtract 5

then, because "bigger" is not defined outside of the `$(function()` scope, `animatebig` is still getting called, hence why the box oscillates in size

Seems more efficient to write your code like this

```
$(function () {
    var numberup = 1;
    var delta = 5;

    function animate(name, dist, time) {
        if (delta > 0 && numberup >= 200) {
            delta = -5;
        }
        else if (numberup < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        $(name).animate({
            left: dist
        }, time);
        $(name).css({
            width: numberup
        });
        numberup += delta;
    }
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        animate('.box1', "+=1", 100)
    }, 100);
});
```

This has a single interval, grow by 5, then shrink by 5 ... you may want to stop once width < 0

For a smoother animation, I'd recommend looking into [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)